# What war assets can be unlocked in ME3 from playing Mass Effect Infiltrator?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-infiltrator

What specific effects can playing Mass Effect Infiltrator have on Galaxy At War in ME3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing Mass Effect: Infiltrator increases your Military Strength by 40. There are no other benefits from playing ME:I that are reflected in Mass Effect 3.

Source: [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/663017-mass-effect-infiltrator/62172967)

Comment: The source is actually very unclear.  To quote:
"The War Room showed my Galactic Readiness at 50%, with 570 War Assets. The "Ex-Cerberus" War Assets that I gained from ME:I were 40, bringing up my Galactic Readiness to 62%. So my Galactic Readiness increased by 12% from playing ME:I."
Galactic Readiness does not equal War Assets.  From playing a bit of ME:I, it looks like every two pieces of intel you upload to the Galaxy at War system gives you 1% toward Galactic Readiness. It's possible only completing the game gives you War Assets, but I can't confirm yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are three permanent Galactic Readiness bonuses.

One for finishing the game (once), one for getting gold on all Main Story checkpoints, and one for getting gold on all Turian Story checkpoints. You can fill all your State of readiness with the ME:I.

[Source](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Galaxy_at_War#Mass_Effect:_Infiltrator).