# What effect do the various Galaxy At War tie-ins have on multiple play throughs?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-infiltrator

If you start a new game of ME3 what effect does your bonuses from Mass Effect: Infiltrator and multiplayer carry over?

Comment: The multiplayer aspect of this is addressed in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54054/does-my-multiplayer-galaxy-at-war-progress-count-towards-all-my-single-player-sa) and Infiltrator is covered a bit in this question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53690/what-are-all-the-ways-to-increase-readiness).

Comment: I agree that the answer to this question has been handled in other questions. Specifically, the Infiltrator question is [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54283/19997).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mass Effect: Infiltrator:

> Throughout each mission, the player can collect intel points which can
>   be uploaded to Mass Effect 3's Galaxy at War system to increase the
>   Galactic Readiness rating or for in-game credits.

For multiplayer:
You can either promote a lvl 20 character and increase galactic readiness. Completing missions increases galactic readiness which determines at what strength your assets are at the final mission. A promoted level 20 character will be added as a war asset.

But as the commenters pointed out, other questions provide a more detailed response
[here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53690/what-are-all-the-ways-to-increase-readiness), [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54283/1770), and [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54054/1770).